# Alexa JSON response - extracting card information

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi, alexa-skills-kit

So I was successfully able to setup my raspberry pi as an alexa device. Now I was wondering whether I could show Alexa's response in text as well, basically the same way http://alexa.amazon.com does it for us. 
Is this possible? I wouldn't want to convert alexa's response from speech tot ext because that seems wasteful since the skills are already sending the text in cards. I just don't know how to retrieve that.

FYI - I have followed this project to setup my raspberry pi for alexa
https://github.com/sammachin/AlexaPi

Answer (score 0):

The Sammachin AlexaPi project only receives an audio file back from Amazon's servers which it plays on the Pi. You may have more luck with the official raspberry pi Alexa app although I'm not sure if that would even output text. Good Luck! https://github.com/amzn/alexa-avs-raspberry-pi

Comment: Basically I want to have an interface just like alexa.amazon.com where I could see the default card response that alexa shows. It doesn't have to be on my pi, maybe as a separate node.js application or something?

I wonder how and from where the webconsole (alexa app) extracts the text response.

Thanks for your response :)

Comment: The cards are available through a web browser meaning you might be able to simply reqest their server send you the same piece of code as they would a browser and then you just display that info through a custom app https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/providing-home-cards-for-the-amazon-alexa-app